# Can Thread.Sleep(Timespan.Zero) be used sensibly in this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-3.5

I am writing a program that reads data packets from a file, and assigns each packet to a specified pipeline for processing.  Each pipeline object has a blocking queue and a filter class.  There can be several such pipelines in operation simultaneously.

The blocking queue just collects packets on the input side until it reaches maximum capacity, at which time it blocks the Queue method until the filter Dequeue's some packets.  The blocking queue is a simple class that uses `Monitor.Wait()` and `Monitor.Pulse()` for synchronization.

Each filter has a `Process()` method that is executed on its own dedicated thread.  It looks something like this:

```
public void Process()
{
    while (!done)
    {
        var packet = sourceQueue.Dequeue();

        //  Perform some filtering operation on packet here

        targetQueue.Enqueue(sourceQueue);

        // Let other threads do some work
        Thread.Sleep(Timespan.Zero);
    }
}
```

**What are the possible pitfalls of using the `Thread.Sleep()` method in this way?**

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/274eh01d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) stipulates that the use of `Thread.Sleep(Timespan.Zero)` *"indicates that this thread should be suspended to allow other waiting threads to execute,"* which is what I want.

But there are blog entries **[like this one](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx)** that basically state that using `Thread.Sleep` is evil.  Why?  Is this a good use of `Thread.Sleep`, or is there a better way?

Comment: Aren't semaphores designed precisely for the capacity situation you mentioned?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't know.  The MSDN documentation says that Semaphore "controls access to a pool of resources."  Wouldn't the `ThreadPool` accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I mean that semaphores place an upper limit on how many threads can access a resource, which if I understand correctly is what you're doing here, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad: The number of threads will be very predictable, unless you're talking about threads outside of my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real programs don't Sleep().

Your suggestion, `Sleep(0)` has an additional problem with allowing only threads with the same priority to run. Generally `Sleep(1)` is considered a little safer. See [Joe Duffy](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,1c013d42-c983-4102-9233-ca54b8f3d1a1.aspx).

But in either case your resolution is ~20ms, which could be way too long.

Your loop as stated does a tiny bit of work and then induces a context switch, very wasteful.

It's a lot better to make the most of a time-slot, so keep working until the Queue blocks you. Blocking is better than sleeping.

Comment: `so keep working until the Queue blocks you` -- That may take awhile, so long as the file is serving packets of that type, and there are other packets in the file that must also be serviced (by other pipelines).  Do I need a high-water and low-water mark on my blocking queue, so that I can make the filter function a little more "chunky?"  Or should I choose an arbitrary number of packets to process at one time?  How would I know what this arbitrary number is?

Comment: @Robert : I left out "or the scheduler pre-empts you", that is always implied and out of your control. But you tune this by capping the Queue, not by sleeping. Re the Edit: Yes, a high-water mark on the Queue.

Answer (score 5):

If you were using .NET 4, I'd personally use [`Thread.Yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.yield.aspx) to make it clearer what you're trying to achieve... but other than that, your sleep looks like it should be *okay* to me... (modulo the choice of 0 or 1, as noted elsewhere) but are you sure it's actually necessary? Have you performed any profiling to check whether it really helps? What's the downside of letting this thread finish its timeslice?

It looks like you're not relying on sleeping for *correctness* which is the thrust of Peter Ritchie's blog post, as far as I can tell... which means it must be for performance reasons. As with *any* tweaks for the sake of performance, you should really measure the performance with and without this, to see whether it's really worthwhile. When in doubt, use the simpler code :)

Comment: @Henk: Ah... I don't think they did when I loaded the page :(

Comment: So are you saying it's possible I don't need to `Sleep()` at all?  That I can just run my loop and leave it to the OS to perform the context switching?

Comment: @Robert: Absolutely. Why do you think you *need* to sleep? What do you think will happen if you don't?

Comment: OK.  I guess I didn't want to hog the thread, but I suppose I overthought it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as performance isn't critical, you'll be fine.

The only down-side to using `Thread.Sleep` is that you don't know how soon you'll get control back, because all of the other threads get processing time before you get it again. As long as you don't care whether its 20ms or 100ms before you get control back, you won't encounter any issues.

Comment: If it's taking a long time to get control back, that means that the other pipelines need the clock cycles, and I do have some rudimentary ways to control that by throttling the pipelines.  So no, I don't really care whether its 20ms or 100 ms.  I guess I should have mentioned that this is not a real-time or near real-time application, although I do need to keep it busy enough to keep the application I/O bound on the hard drives.

Answer (score 1):

If there is work to do, whay not do it?  Unless there are further contraints on you system, it would seem reasonable to filter all the input until the queue is empty, as John suggests.  The other pipeline threads will be doing much the same, so they should all get their work done.

If your issue is that the work done by your 'filtering operation' is quite small and so you want to process them in chunks to mitigate excessive context switches maybee you could either:

1) Use fewer threads by passing the required 'filtering operation' in with the packet, ie. as a method of the packet.  Fewer threads could then do a broader range of jobs, so increasing the load on each thread and reducing context-switch/packet.  It would be kinda useful if any thread could do any filter operation, but I realise that this is not always possible.

2) Load a number of packet objects onto a list/queue/stack and push this construct onto the thread queue.

Another couple of points for consideration:

Beware of 'monitor-pulse' and 'event-signal' producer-consumer queues.  I have seen many attempts at this which are seriously flawed, expecially with multiple producers and multiple CPU.  Problems arise when consuming because the act of checking the queue for empty and the act of waiting on the monitor/event are not one atomic operation.  I've yet to be convinced that such a queue can be made to work reliably at all in the general case.  It may well be fine if there is only one producer/consumer, so you may be OK, but bear this in mind if strange things happen when your app is loaded up.  'Computer Science 117' producer-consumer queues use semaphores for producers/consumers to wait on and to count the queue entries atomically.  Your queue entries are a 'pool of resources' to which 'access control' needs to be applied, ie. exactly what MSDN says that a semaphore provides.

Load management.  You are using bounded queues, which is fine.  Another possibility that can either provide better overall performance, or worse, (again - this is a suggestion that may be useful or not, depending on the details of your app), is to restrict the total number of packets available in your system by creating a pool of them at startup, (pool could be another P-C queue with all the packets pushed on).  This scheme throttles all the producers when the pool becomes empty - they have to wait until the consumers release 'used' packets back to the pool, and you don't need bounded queues.

Rgds,
Martin

```
    public void Enqueue(UInt64 key, T item)
    {
        while (queue.Count >= MaximumSize)
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.Zero);

        lock (queue)
        {
            queue.Add(key, item);

            if (queue.Count > PeakSize)
                PeakSize = queue.Count;

            Monitor.Pulse(queue);
        }
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            while (!flushed && queue.Count < MinimumSize)
                Monitor.Wait(queue);

            var item = queue.First();
            T value = item.Value;
            queue.Remove(item.Key);

            return value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Problems arise when consuming because the act of checking the queue for empty and the act of waiting on the monitor/event are not one atomic operation.`  The collection object is locked during each of these operations, using the same locking object (the collection that implements the queue).  My understanding is this makes the actions atomic.  I can show you the code for the blocking queues if you want to see it; it's not much code.

Comment: Yes please post it.  I am sure that you are safely locking the queue when objects are being pushed/popped, but I can't see, for example, how the consumer wait can be inside the lock - the producer/s could not then get in to push a new object before pulsing the monitor.

Comment: I put the `Enqueue()` and `Dequeue()` methods of my blocking queue in your answer, and upvoted.

Comment: Hmm.. not sure.  A consumer waits on the monitor because the queue is empty.  A producer adds an object and leaves the lock section.  At this point the consumer that was waiting on the monitor tries to acquire the lock again.  Three things could now get the lock - the comsumer that was waiting, another consumer or a producer. Is that right?  It is somewhat unclear, looking a docs for Monitor, what exactly happens at that point. If another consumer can get the lock, it could empty the queue before the consumer that was waiting, leaving the consumer that was waiting to pop an empty queue?

Comment: @Martin : this looks quite alright, that's why the Wait() is in a `while()`. But I do see problems when flushed==true or when the Queue has to be emptied.

Comment: OK, good luck with your app.  I just had to say something 'cos of all the dodgy queue implementations I have seen.  I guess I could now moan about the sleep(0) spin, but would seem kinda cruel, somehow.. <g>